# What is this JS function doing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm working on converting an `array utilities` file from js to typescript on an open source project. It's been pretty easy to convert most functions, but I'm not understanding what this one is doing.

```
/**
 * sort array by numeric by numeric property values
 * of object entries. null entries are treated as 0.
 * array entries must be objects.
 * @param {object[]} arr
 * @param {string} prop - numeric property to sort on.
 */
export const propSort = (arr,prop) => {

    arr.sort( (a,b)=>{
        return ( a[prop] || 0 ) - ( b[prop] || 0 );
    });

}
```

I have a description for what the function is supposed to be doing, as is listed above the function. But I don't understand the syntax. Apparently prop is supposed to be a string. But if that's the case, what exactly are a, b? How do you get the value out of an array using a string? And are there any pitfalls in converting this function to typescript?

Comment: `a` and `b` are two separate elements of `arr`. You can refer to [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for additional info; specifically, any contained references to the `compareFn` argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is essentially a wrapper around the [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method of arrays. If you pass `.sort()` a callback, it will pass that call back the two elements it is comparing for sorting purposes. Your callback then returns a value to determine which of the two elements should come first by returning a positive value (`a` comes after `b`), negative value (`a` comes before `b`), or zero (they are equal and their relative order doesn't matter).

The `propSort()` function just runs `.sort()` and returns the result, but passes `.sort()` a callback function. The idea of the callback function is that every element of `arr` is an object and you want to sort each object by a property that every object has.

Comment: Didn't realize ChatGPT answer were banned, thanks for the heads up. Sorry about that. It makes sense that they would be banned though, it won't happen again :)